# While running PowerShell 6 in PowerShell ISE windows get's hanged and no input

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I recently installed the PowerShell 6* version on windows server 2016. While i try to run pwsh.exe in PowerShell ISE, windows get hanged and it's return nothing for more input. Please refer below screenshot for same. Anyone faced same issue please let me solutions or work around for it.
[Screenshot of PowerShell windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfJxZ.png)

Comment: As far as I know Powershell_ISE only supports Windows Powershell. No Powershell 6 or 7. I recommend [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com) instead.

Comment: I Download powershell 6.2 version and running powershell 6.2 in Cmd via "pwsh.exe" which is working fine but when i try the same in powershell ISE it gets hanged.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish actually?

Comment: I want to run PowerShell 6.2 version in PowerShell ISE by running command "pwsh.exe" command, but it not running and PS ISE windows get hanged there(Please refer Image in Question for same).

Comment: No. Why do you want to run Powershell 6.2 in ISE? What is the problem you want to solve with this. If you want to develop scripts for Powershell 6 or higher you should use VSCode. Powershell_ISE does not support Powershell 6.

Comment: I have one script which is initially developed in PS5.1 in that script i am calling one command which is `Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "API-URL" -Method Post -Body $json -SessionVariable session`  Now i want to use additional parameters in same line which is `-RetryIntervalSec 10 -MaximumRetryCount 3` which is not supported by PS5.1, it's only supported by PS6.2. In this script there are other commands which is not running in PS6.2 like `Get-DnsClientServerAddress` and `Get-NetIPAddress` so i am trying to run this script in PowerShell_ISE.

Comment: You cannot mix cmdlets only supported in one version of Powershell and expect them to run in the unsupported version. As the Powershell_ISE is only inteded to be used for development purposes you should use the normal Powershell to run your script.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, but usually newer version always support older version functionalities, so i was hoping for PS5.1 and PS6.2 as well. I Tried to to run pwsh.exe in normal PowerShell windows it's worked there not same not working in PS_ISE. Still i am struggling with another issue in PowerShell core https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59263965/unable-to-import-module-dnsclient-module-in-powershell-coreps6-2

Comment: You aren't supposed to run interactive console applications inside ISE at all. That's not a supported scenario, and is not unique to pwsh.exe

Answer (score 1):

As the comments on your question indicate, you should switch up to Visual Studio Code for PowerShell development. ISE is not regularly updated to support later versions of PowerShell.

[What's New in PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-in-the-powershell-50-ise?view=powershell-7)

> The PowerShell ISE is no longer in active feature development. As a shipping component of Windows, it continues to be officially supported for security and high-priority servicing fixes. We currently have no plans to remove the ISE from Windows.
>
> There is no support for the ISE in PowerShell v6 and beyond. Users looking for replacement for the ISE should use Visual Studio Code with the PowerShell Extension.

As far as commands that are not PowerShell Core specific, you should update to PowerShell 7 and see if your compatibility issues with those modules are resolved. There has been a lot of work into compatibility and perhaps you'll be able to use these modules now, or find a more up to date alternative.

For PowerShell Core 6, you can also look at `WindowsCompatibility` module. I've been told that this is not required in PowerShell 7, but it was helpful for me on v6 to better leverage WindowsPowerShell modules while I was in my `pwsh.exe` session.