# Unable to Import-module DnsClient module in PowerShell core(PS6.2)

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

Unable to `Import-module DnsClient` module in PowerShell core(PS6.2), I recently installed PowerShell 6.2 and trying to run `Get-DnsClientServerAddress`.

Getting Error:

> The term 'Get-DnsClientServerAddress' is not recognized as the name of
>   cmdlet,function, script file.

I tried to resolve this by running the below command.

```
import-module DnsClient -SkipEditionCheck
```

But again getting the error:

```
Could not load type 'System.Management.Automation.PSSnapIn' from assembly 'System.Management.Automation, Version=6.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
```

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this, works fine for me on Windows 10 1809 and PS Core 6.2.3

Comment: I am using Windows Server 2016. I Installed the PowerShell 6.2 with command ```iex "& { $(irm https://aka.ms/install-powershell.ps1) } -UseMSI" ```. Can you please mention steps?

Comment: I've downloaded latest stable release and installed it manually: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v6.2.3/PowerShell-6.2.3-win-x64.msi